# Solving the system of equations for $23\times 23$ matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes, systems-of-equations, self-learning, markov-chains, transition-matrix

I have to solve the following system of equations (which appeared while obtaining limiting distribution of a Markov chain) manually without using software. Any suggestion which way to think or how to start, as it will take a lot of time in solving them in usual manner.

Further I would like to state that the value of only  $\pi_1 $ has been asked to find, 
and it must equal $\frac{1}{23}$, so if that can be obtained without calculating rest of the values i.e if there is some other idea or concept that I am not able to think of, please let me know.

\begin{align*}
\pi_1 &=  \frac {1}{2} \pi_{23} + \frac {1}{2} \pi_2 \\
\pi_2 &=  \frac {1}{2} \pi_1  + \frac {1}{2} \pi_3\\
\pi_3 &=  \frac {1}{2} \pi_2  + \frac {1}{2} \pi_4\\
\pi_4 &=  \frac {1}{2} \pi_3  + \frac {1}{2} \pi_5\\
&\ \ \,\vdots\qquad \ \ \ \, \vdots\\          
\pi_{21} &=  \frac {1}{2} \pi_{20}  + \frac {1}{2} \pi_{22}\\
\pi_{22} &=  \frac {1}{2} \pi_{21}  + \frac {1}{2} \pi_{23}\\
\pi_{23} &=   \frac {1}{2} \pi_{22} + \frac {1}{2} \pi_1.\\
\end{align*}

Comment: How does "manually" include "asking MSE"?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is easy to see that having all the $\pi_i$ equal to each other gives a solution.

I assume you also want $\sum \pi_i$ to be $1$. This would give the solution $\pi_i = \frac{1}{23}$.

I didn't explain why that is the unique solution.

Comment: To OP: The chain is (apparently) aperiodic, irreducible, and positive recurrent (because it is finite), so the solution is unique.